# Is possible use the same POJO in two different serializations, customizing some properties?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I want to use the same DTO but in some cases I need to ignore some properties and in other cases I want to use it, but I don't want to do a duplicate object or custom serialization, exist some way to specify, if the DTO is used on this implementation ignore this properties, and if DTO is used in other implementation don't ignore the properties.

I'm using *jackson* to serialize the DTO

```
public abstract class BaseAuditDto extends BaseIdentifiableDto {



    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6010447982202996167L;

    @JsonIgnore

    private String createdBy;


    @JsonIgnore

    private Date createdDate;


    @JsonIgnore

    private String updatedBy;


    @JsonIgnore 

    private Date updatedDate;


    //getters and setters   

}
```

Basically I need to use in some cases the createdBy and createdDate but in other cases I don't need it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`Jackson` views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews):

> "Views" in this context mean ability to define subsets of logical
>   properties (things accessed via getters or fields) to serialize. Views
>   are defined statically (using annotations), but view to use for
>   serialization is chosen dynamically (per serialization).

**EDIT**
I think that I misunderstood your question. You can use views but it will be a really tricky and hard to understand. You can use [MixIn feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations), which will be much easier to implement. Assume that you have two `POJO` classes:

```
class Pojo1 extends BaseAuditDto {

    private String name;

    //getters, setters
}
```

and

```
class Pojo2 extends BaseAuditDto {

    private String description;

    //getters, setters

}
```

Now we have to create interface with getters from `BaseAuditDto` class. It can look like this:

```
interface BaseAuditDtoIgnorePropertiesMixIn {
    @JsonIgnore
    String getCreatedBy();
    @JsonIgnore
    Date getCreatedDate();
    @JsonIgnore
    String getUpdatedBy();
    @JsonIgnore
    Date getUpdatedDate();
}
```

As you can see, above interface defines annotations for methods which are exists in `BaseAuditDto` class. Now, we have to tell to `Jackson` for which classes we want to ignore above properties. See below code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Pojo1.class, BaseAuditDtoIgnorePropertiesMixIn.class);
```

Now, we can test our classes:

```
Pojo1 pojo1 = new Pojo1();
pojo1.setCreatedBy("me");
pojo1.setCreatedDate(new Date());
pojo1.setUpdatedBy("you");
pojo1.setUpdatedDate(new Date());
pojo1.setId(1);
pojo1.setName("Name");

Pojo2 pojo2 = new Pojo2();
pojo2.setCreatedBy("me");
pojo2.setCreatedDate(new Date());
pojo2.setUpdatedBy("you");
pojo2.setUpdatedDate(new Date());
pojo2.setId(2);
pojo2.setDescription("Description");

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo1));
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo2));
```

Above code prints:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Name"}
{"id":2,"createdBy":"me","createdDate":1403653155395,"updatedBy":"you","updatedDate":1403653155395,"description":"Description"}
```

As you can see, `Jackson` ignores `BaseAuditDto` properties for `Pojo1` class.

Comment: I'm using the jackson 2.4 and JsonViews doen't work for me, could you provide me some examples?

Comment: I understood the JsonViews, now my question is, is possible set two or more @JsonViews to the same property?

Comment: My example shows `MixIn` feature not `JsonView`. Answer for your question: I am not sure, probably not.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK if you intend to serialise/deserialise the object (using standard functionality) you have to provide and then expect all values, your serialVersionUID defines the format of serialised data.

When you convert the data to JSON or XML it is another story - you can provide/omit some properties as the format is verbose enough to prevent erroneous assignments.